# How to add a vimrc path to vim

Tags: vim

currently there are a few paths where .vimrc files are being searched. (as can be seen in `:scriptnames` command).

How do I add another path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `'runtimepath'` option specifies the locations of the Vim configuration subdirectories (i.e. directories containing `autoload/`, `plugin/`, `syntax/`, etc.) The *Pathogen* plugin made it popular to extend this so that each plugin is installed into a separate such subdirectory, and other plugin managers (like Vundle) do that as well.

Now, there's only one `.vimrc` (and you can change its location via the `-u` command-line argument), but nothing prevents you from using `:source path/to/another/script.vim` to load other Vim scripts during startup.

#### TL;DR

To execute a separate Vimscript file during startup, just `:source` it from your `~/.vimrc`. If you have a plugin(s) that you want to install in a separate location, use `:set runtimepath+=path/to/pluginroot` in your `~/.vimrc`, or just use Pathogen or another plugin manager.

Answer (score 2):

You're mistaken. `:scriptnames` tells you which scripts were loaded. It will be:

- `.vimrc`,
- possibly `.gvimrc`,
- plus all plugins in `'runtimepath'`,
- plus all ftplugins, syntax files and indent files in `runtimepath` that apply for all the buffers you have edited,
- plus the autoload plugins loaded by the previous files,
- plus the files you've sourced manually.

If you want to change the places where to search for your .vimrc, it will be more complex as vim has a very specific heuristic to search for a `.vimrc`. See `:h startup`.

---

Any way. If you really want to add a path where the `.vimrc` file will be searched, it's not possible unless you define an alias to vim that use the `-u` flags.

If you want to add other paths where to look for plugins, you'll have to set the `'runtimepath'` option in your `.vimrc`. For instance, `:set rtp+=~/.vim/addon/foobar` will have all plugins named `$HOME/.vim/addon/foo/plugin/*.vim` and `$HOME/.vim/addon/foo/after/plugin/*.vim` loaded automatically, plus the ftplugin/syntax file/indent files loaded automatically as well if you enable them, and when you enter a buffer related to them.